# Windows Forms: Accessing Control Appearance Properties

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I'm trying to change the property FlatStyle of a control according to a configuration SQL table that I created. Right now I can enable or disable controls, I have research for hours and have found nothing. Any ideas?, I have tried this `Me.Controls.Find(controlName,True).fistOrDefault().FlatStyle= FlatStyle.Flat` no luck.

Here's the code:

```
    For each dr As DataRow In controlListDataset.Tables(0).Rows
        controlName = dr.Item("controlName")
        labelName = dr.Item("labelName")
        activeStatus = dr.Item("TrueOrFalse")
        Me.Controls.Find(controlName,True).fistOrDefault().Enabled = activeStatus
        Me.Controls.Find(labelName,True).fistOrDefault().Enabled = activeStatus
        If activeStatus then
              Me.Controls.Find(controlName,True).fistOrDefault().FlatStyle= FlatStyle.Flat
        else
              Me.Controls.Find(controlName,True).fistOrDefault().FlatStyle= FlatStyle.Standard
        Endif
    Next
```

Comment: Some programming problems can't be fixed with fists.  You'd **first** favor `Option Explicit On`.

Comment: Does this compile even with `Option Explicit Off` ?

Comment: `Option Explicit`  is on @HansPassant

Comment: I turned it off and no don't compile. Get a `'FlatStyle; is not a memeber of 'Control'`  @JQSOFT

Comment: Never turn it off buddy. You need to do something like: `Dim b = Controls.Find(controlName, True).OfType(Of Button).FirstOrDefault : If b IsNot Nothing Then b.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Popup` or whatever you want.

Comment: @JQSOFT That works, Thanks.

Comment: @JQSOFT, did you mean `Option Strict` rather than `Option Explicit`? That latter is `On` by default but the former is `Off` and, unfortunately, fat too few beginners are even taught that it exists, never mind to turn it `On` and leave it `On`.

Comment: If you are calling `FirstOrDefault` and immediately accessing a member of the result then you clearly don't know what that method does. The whole point is that it returns the first item in a sequence or the default value of the relevant type if there are no items, which means `Nothing` for classes. If there definitely are items then you should be calling `First` rather than `FirstOrDefault` but if it might return `Nothing` then you need to test for that.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Absolutely right. Just followed Mr. Hans's comment to say the problem is beyond that. In other words I meant  either the `Option Explicit` is on or off, the code won't compile due to the missing cast.